# Python: Creating a Gaussian distribution for a variable and running a program on a loop using the Gaussian values

Tags: python

I am still getting my feet with python and am struggling to solve this problem:

I am running a script in python using a toolkit named Fatiando a Terra; where I define the parameters of a body and then model it with gravity/gradiometry, as follows:

```
import numpy as np
from fatiando.vis import mpl
from fatiando.mesher import Prism
from fatiando.gravmag import prism
from fatiando.constants import G
from fatiando import utils
import fatiando
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

model = Prism(-1000, 1000, -1000, 1000, 1000, 1100, {'density': 300})
n = 500
x = np.zeros(n)
y = np.zeros(n)
z = np.linspace(0, 2000, n)
data = np.array([prism.gx(x, y, z, [model]),
                 prism.gy(x, y, z, [model]),
                 prism.gz(x, y, z, [model]),
                 prism.gxx(x, y, z, [model]),
                 prism.gxy(x, y, z, [model]),
                 prism.gxz(x, y, z, [model]),
                 prism.gyy(x, y, z, [model]),
                 prism.gyz(x, y, z, [model]),
                 prism.gzz(x, y, z, [model])])
```

Following this, I am plotting it using python, however this code is not relevant.

I have performed a tiny Gaussian array manually, using:

```
from numpy.random import multivariate_normal
multivariate_normal([300]. [[300]], 10)
```

The 10 values it provided me I manually entered into my script and generated outputs.

**What I am trying to do is to perform a Gaussian distribution +-100 on the density value of 300. I want to generate 1000 values and loop them back into the script, running the program 1000 times, once for each density variant.**

For output, I am currently using:

```
titles = ['gx', 'gy', 'gz', 'gxx', 'gxy', 'gxz', 'gyy', 'gyz', 'gzz']
np.savetxt(title, np.vstack((z.ravel(), d.ravel())).T)
```

**Ideally, for the Gaussian array I would like to output text in the same fashion, but using the mean value of the 1000 samples rather than any individual value. Also standard deviation would be great.**

---

Apologies if I am asking too much, and a massive thanks for any help available.
Cheers!

Comment: why don't you call your current code in a function with `density` as a parameter, and you call that 1000 times in a loop?

Comment: Thank you. I understand that in principle, but I am still in the early days of learning the code and don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is more of an extended comment than an answer, though it may also serve as the latter.

Wrapping your code in a function, then calling that function in a loop, averaging the result at the end, could look something like this (partly symbolic):

```
##import statements

NDENSITIES = 1000

def dowork(density):
    model = Prism(-1000, 1000, -1000, 1000, 1000, 1100, {'density': 300})
    ##other code
    return data   ## or whatever is important

densities = multivariate_normal([300], [[300]], NDENSITIES)
results = []
for density in range(densities):
    results.append(dowork(density))
results = np.vstack(results)   ## or hstack or dstack, depending on the dimensions of `data`
mean = results.mean()   # possibly: results.mean(axis=0) or with axis=1 etc. Again dependent on the dimensions
std = results.std()
```

Comment: Thank you again. This is great for me to begin with, it looks nicer than anything I came up with.